# I want to get the data in my table which is an enum data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a table 'companies' with 'approval' as a column with enum type data ('Need Approval', 'Approved).
I want to change the color of the text if the approval is Approved with green color, and else with red.

```
$data = DB::table('companies')
    ->select('approval')
    ->get();
    

    if($data == 'Approved')
    {
        return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:green'>".$this->approval."</span>";
    }
    else 
    {
        return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:orange'>".$this->approval."</span>";
    }
    //return '<span style="color:red">'.$this->approval.'<span>'>'.';
}
```

but The Result always shows the Else clause. Can someone help ?

Comment: when you use `get()` it returns object. so, if condition will always be false and hence it returns else

Comment: if you are fetching multiple records then you need to use foreach loop. tell me if you are fetching multiple records or single record?

Comment: it is for showing multiple records

Comment: then use `first()` instead of `get()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks a lot guys i just made a little change

```
public function changeColor()
{       
    $data = DB::table('companies')
    ->select('approval')
    ->first();
    
        if($this->approval == 'Approved')
        {
            return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:green'>".$this->approval."</span>";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:orange'>".$this->approval."</span>";
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The if statement will always return false because $data is an object and you are comparing object (that contains all your companies approval column) to string.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i've finished my problem before with a little repair

```
$data = DB::table('companies')
    ->select('approval')
    ->first();
    foreach ($data as $datas)
    //     {
            if($data->approval == 'Approved')
            {
                return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:green'>".$this->approval."</span>";
            }
            else 
            {
                return "<span class='badge' style='background-color:orange'>".$this->approval."</span>";
            }
```

Now i have a new problem, if i create more than 1 data. The colour cannot separated based on the status

[the approved should be green, if its not approved it should be orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE9lm.png)

Comment: the color always following the first data, please helpp